# How can I run a TYPO3 extension in cron jobs?

Tags: cron, typo3

Can anyone tell me how to setup a cronjob in TYPO3? I've created a TYPO3 extension which I want to run once a week. I've already installed the **scheduler** extension, but it only allows some extensions (e.g., **tt_news** ) to be executed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your extension must support the `Scheduler` - system extension (maybe you'll need to install it first). Therefore you have to register your extension in the Scheduler Service.

via your `ext_localconf.php`

```
if (!defined ('TYPO3_MODE')) die ('Access denied.');

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['scheduler']['tasks']['TX_YOUR_EXTENSIONKEY'] = array(
    'extension'        => $_EXTKEY,
    'title'            => 'Some meningful Title',
    'description'      => 'Some Discription of the Task'
);
```

you need to create the file `tasks/class.TX_YOUREXTENSKEY.php` in your extension directory

```
class TX_YOUREXTENSKEY extends tx_scheduler_Task {
    public function execute() {}
    ...
}
```

the execute function is called if the task gets executed. it should return true if everything went fine and false if you got some error.

at last your class needs to be loaded this can be done using `ext_autoload.php` (in your extension root, see [TYPO3 Wiki: Autoload](http://wiki.typo3.org/Autoload) for more details)

```
<?php
  return array(
    'tx_sfpinger_pinger' => t3lib_extMgm::extPath('sfpinger', 'tasks/class.tx_sfpinger_pinger.php')
  );
?>
```

Finally you need to add to your system cron command that will be running `Scheduler` ext periodically (you'll find it on the Scheduler's `Setup check` section) and also add your created task to the its tasks list.

You can check a [demo task](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/sm_scheddemo) which is just a sample from which you can copy code and paste in your extension.

Also check documentation delivered with scheduler task in folder on your TYPO3 implementation: `/typo3/sysext/scheduler/doc/manual.sxw`

Comment: Ok. works fine but when I want to save the task, I get this error: Fatal error: Class 'extension_name' not found in Cpath\class.t3lib_div.php on line 4849

Comment: Error soved, php extension was missing

Comment: @CristiCalacianu Mark the question as answered than